# Continuous stream compression that is safe to interrupt

Tags: linux, shell, stream, compression, gzip

I have a lot of data coming in which I am piping to gzip. The data comes in a continuous stream, so there is no end of it. When I stop the program using C^c and try to decompress, I get an error about the end of the file. How can I end up with a compressed output file? The reason is that I want to have my data saved if the computer restarts, unplugs, etc.

`$ yes | gzip > out.gz
$ gzip -d out.gz
gzip: blah.gz: unexpected end of file`

I'm not attached to gzip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work with `compress`:

```
yes | compress >out.Z
uncompress -c out.Z
```

Comment: Great, it works. Would be better with preinstalled tools (I had to do `apt-get install ncompress`, but solves my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Since you store compressed data -- you must be prepared to lost some blocs of data (few kB) corresponding to the current sliding window if it is abruptly interrupted. Not mentioning the fact your disk/OS probably have large cache that would lead to even larger loss in case of power outage.

For what it worth, I launched the following command, interrupting it at some point:

```
sh$ yes | nl |  tee >(cat > master) >(compress >out.Z) > /dev/null
^C
```

Now, in the file `master` I have the raw (uncompressed) data, and in `out.Z` the corresponding compressed data. Or this is what you might expect. But, compare both the master file and the data extracted from the compressed file, and you will notice that some records are missing at the end:

```
sh$ tail -3 master
11937063    y
11937064    y
119370

sh$ uncompress -c out.Z | tail -3
11936691    y
11936692    y
11
```

If I'm not too wrong, that is 372 (very short) lines missing. From `wc` I found that corresponds to 4 kiB in that particular run.

```
sh$ U=$(uncompress -c out.Z | wc -c)
sh$ R=$(wc -c < master)
sh$ echo $(((R-U)/1024))
4
```

Repeating the test several times, I have results between 0KiB and 8KiB.
Repeating the test but interrupting by ctrl-z (sleep), I have results up to 24-28 kiB (I *guess* SIGSTOP won't flush some caches whereas SIGINT does).

Depending on your needs, this might or might not be acceptable. And remember this was only been interrupted by pressing ^C/^Z. I bet results might be way worst in case of power outage...

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is acceptable to lose a bit of the most recent data.